# php- How to strip CSS in the text

Tags: php, html, css, strip-tags

I have a text editor where user can enter raw `HTML` as a description. In some cases, there are some `CSS` styles in the text editor. I want to skip through the `CSS` and work only on string.

**Raw HTML**

```
    <style type="text/css">.textleft{
    margin-bottom:10px;
    float:left; 
    display: inline-block;
    width:56%;
    text-align:left;
    padding-right:20px;
    padding-left:20px;
}
  .textleft > p { display: table-cell; height: 150px; vertical-align: middle; }


.imageblock{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    width: 44%;
}

.textright{
    margin-bottom:10px;
    float:right; 
    display: inline-block;
    width:56%;
    text-align:left;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
}

.containerz{
    display:block;
}


.featimage{
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-block;
    width:53%;
    max-height:245px;
}

.features{
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-block;
    width:46%;
    padding-left:30px;
}

.textright > p { display: table-cell; height: 150px; vertical-align: middle; }

@media screen and (max-width: 991px)   {
    .textleft, .textright, .imageblock{
        width:100%;   
        float:none;
        padding-left: 0px;
        padding-right: 0px;
    }   
    /*.imageblock > img { width:100%;}*/
    .containerz {text-align:center;}
    .textright > p, .textleft > p { height: 100%; }
    .textright, .textleft { margin-bottom: 0px; }
    .features, .featimage { padding-left: 0px; width:100%; float:none;}
    .features { padding-top: 10px;}
    .imageblock {margin-bottom: 25px;}
}
</style>
<h1><strong>WhiteCoat Clipboard<sup>&reg;</sup> - TEAL&nbsp;- Vertical Metric Medical Edition</strong></h1>
```

**PHP strip_tags**

```
$description  = utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($product_info['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, 200) . '..',
```

above code only works if there are no `CSS` rules in `$product_info['description']`

for the above `HTML`, I get this

```
.textleft{ margin-bottom:10px; float:left; display: inline-block; width:56%; text-align:left; padding-right:20px; padding-left:20px; } .textleft > p { display: ..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there exists a function for it, but this will do it:

```
$a = <<<EOH
<style type="text/css">
.textleft{
.... (your css stuff here)....
}
</style>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias blanditiis deserunt eligendi error est exercitationem ipsum laudantium minima mollitia rem! Aliquid amet aspernatur blanditiis consectetur deleniti dignissimos ducimus, illo iusto libero maxime nulla odit quasi quidem, quis quod sint unde velit vitae? Ab assumenda eos facere molestiae nesciunt provident voluptatum?

EOH;
$a = preg_replace('/<style(.*)<\/style>/s', '', $a);
var_dump($a);
```

output: string '
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias blanditiis deserunt eligendi error est exercitationem ipsum laudantium minima mollitia rem! Aliquid amet aspernatur blanditiis consectetur deleniti dignissimos ducimus, illo iusto libero maxime nulla odit quasi quidem, quis quod sint unde velit vitae? Ab assumenda eos facere molestiae nesciunt provident voluptatum?
' (length=382)

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't remove any tags, output comes with the `style` tags

Comment: It works for me. hmm.. are you sure that in $product_info['description'] is really what you posted (verified it with a echo $product_info['description']) ?

Comment: yes that's exactly what I posted. did you try it woth my `html` ?

Comment: I have tried it with what I posted and what you posted, both succesfull.